# MySQL does not generating PID file

Tags: mysql, linux

I upgraded my OS from redhat 2.6.3 to 2.6.5 after that
when I restarted my MySQL server but it not started,

error message is "**150320 11:53:17 [ERROR] Error message file '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys' had only 641 error messages,
but it should contain at least 728 error messages.**" and when I fired the command service mysql start it giving error "**Starting MySQL......The server quit without updating PID file (/var/mysql-data/hostname.pid).                                            [FAILED]**"

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

I got the sollution:

1. Extract your new MySQL file:

   ```
   tar -zxf mysql-5.1.58.tar.gz
   ```
2. Rename the old `errmsg.sys` file showing in the error message

   ```
   mv /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys.old
   ```
3. Copy the new `errmsg.sys` file to existing location:

   ```
   cp mysql-5.1.58/sql/share/english/errmsg.sys /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys
   ```
4. Start your server:

   ```
   service mysql start
   ```

Detail explanation can be found [here](http://toastergremlin.com/?p=447).